# In Rcpp - how to return a vector with names

Tags: r, rcpp

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
testM <- as.matrix(read.table(textConnection("
1  5  4  1  3  2
2  1  5  4  1  3
2  2  1  5  4  1
3  2  2  1  5  4
1  3  2  2  1  5
4  1  3  2  2  1
1  5  4  1  3  2
2  1  5  4  1  3
2  2  1  5  4  1
3  2  2  1  5  4
1  3  2  2  1  5
4  1  3  2  2  1
")))
```

This matrix has column names `V1` to `V6`

Suppose that there is another matrix where I remove the column name:

```
> testM2<-testM
> colnames(testM2)<-NULL
```

Then if I try `colMeans` on `testM` and `testM2` R returns a `numeric` class in both cases, except in the first case the answer has `colnames`.

```
> colMeans(testM)
      V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6 
2.166667 2.333333 2.833333 2.500000 2.666667 2.666667 
> colMeans(testM2)
[1] 2.166667 2.333333 2.833333 2.500000 2.666667 2.666667
```

Now suppose I have the same function written in RCpp as follows:

```
double do_mean(NumericVector x) {
  return mean(na_omit(x));
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector colMeansCppMt(NumericMatrix& x) {
  int nCols=x.ncol();
  NumericVector out=no_init(nCols);
  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    NumericMatrix::Column tmp=x(_,i);
    out[i]=do_mean(tmp);
  }
  return out;
}
```

The output for `colMeansCppMt` for both `testM` and `testM2` return numeric vectors, but the one for `testM` does not contain the `colnames` as it hasn't been set.

Now, suppose I change the `colMeansCppMt` function to include attributes like this:

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector colMeansCppMt(NumericMatrix& x) {
  int nCols=x.ncol();
  NumericVector out=no_init(nCols);
  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    NumericMatrix::Column tmp=x(_,i);
    out[i]=do_mean(tmp);
  }
  out.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
  return out;
}
```

The output for `testM` is still a vector that doesn't contain the column names.

I also tried `out.attr("names")=x.attr("colnames")` and `out.attr("colnames")=x.attr("colnames")`.

a). How can I check in RCpp where the `colnames` of a matrix (e.g. `x` in the example function above) has been set or not?

b). How can I return a numeric vector in R with names in Rcpp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the landscape:

1. Regular R vectors have an (optional) `names` attribute,
2. `data.frame`s have a `row.names` attribute for rows, and `names` attribute for columns, and
3. `matrix`s have an (optional) `dimnames` attribute; this attribute is a `list` containing 2 character vectors (rows then columns).

So what you want is the column names of `x` attached to the 'names' attribute of `out`, so something like:

```
out.attr("names") = VECTOR_ELT(x.attr("dimnames"), 1);
```

would work.

(I cannot recall if `Rcpp` has a nice API for getting / setting dimension names in arrays...)