# Rcpp - how to check if any attribute is NULL

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a `Rcpp` function that accepts a NumericMatrix and returns a NumericVector. In my code I have a line based on recommendations by Kevin Ushey here: [In Rcpp - how to return a vector with names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393025/in-rcpp-how-to-return-a-vector-with-names) that assigns column names of the NumericMatrix to the NumericVector :

`out.attr("names")=VECTOR_ELT(inp.attr("dimnames"),1)`

This code gives an error if the NumericMatrix didn't have column names, i..e `colnames(inp)=NULL`. How can I check in `Rcpp` if the `VECTOR_ELT(inp.attr("dimnames"),1)` is `NULL`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want `Rf_isNull`:

```
SEXP dm = inp.attr("dimnames");
if (!Rf_isNull(dm) && Rf_length(dm) > 1) {
    out.attr("names") = VECTOR_ELT(dm, 1);
}
```

FWIW, because of this awkwardness we will likely be adding `rownames`, `colnames` convenience methods to `Rcpp` sometime in the future.

(The length check is just to make sure that there is actually something to find at index `1` of the `dimnames` attribute)

Comment: that would be quite useful

Comment: Now in the development version of [Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp): [commit](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/commit/61829557cf935c3d512cc8a3d5c3e39ff815ab5c)